# How to load and test a model in pytorch?

Tags: python, image-processing, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am loading an already trained dataset. My dataset is a 3D image and i want to test that model now. So I created a different function but is showing an error at. i tried to save using state_dict() first but it showed an error, so I saved the whole model.

```
My = MyNet(data)
My = torch.load("model_par.pt")
```

The error is:

```
File "main_SUDF.py", line 238, in <module>
My = MyNet(data)
File "main_SUDF.py", line 148, in __init__
self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(input_dim, nChannel, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py", line 410, in __init__
super(Conv2d, self).__init__(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py", line 50, in __init__
if in_channels % groups != 0:
RuntimeError: Boolean value of Tensor with more than one value is ambiguous
```

and my model is:

```
class MyNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim):
        super(MyNet, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(input_dim, nChannel, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(nChannel)
        self.pool1 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        self.conv2 = []
        self.bn2 = []
        self.pool2 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        for i in range(nConv - 1):
            self.conv2.append(nn.Conv2d(nChannel, nChannel, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1))
            self.bn2.append(nn.BatchNorm2d(nChannel))

        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(nChannel, nChannel, kernel_size=1, stride=1, padding=0)
        self.bn3 = nn.BatchNorm2d(nChannel)
        self.UB1 = nn.UpsamplingBilinear2d(scale_factor=2)
        self.deconv = nn.ConvTranspose2d(nChannel, nChannel, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.bn1(x)
        x = self.pool1(x)
        for i in range(nConv - 1):
            x = self.conv2[i](x)
            x = F.relu(x)
            x = self.bn2[i](x)
            if i == 0:
                x = self.pool2(x)
        x = self.conv3(x)
        # x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.bn3(x)

        x = self.UB1(x)
        x = self.deconv(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.bn3(x)

        x = self.UB1(x)
        x = self.deconv(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.bn3(x)

        return x
```

Comment: The recommended way to save and load models is by using the state_dict() method on your model. What was the error when you tried to save using `torch.save(My.state_dict(),'model_par.pth')`?

Comment: I don't remember exactly, but it was I think " cant call ordered dict object". maybe I could have saved it by instantiating the model first. But I have now save my model as a whole.